# Terraform Setting a Bash Variable in local-exec How to Include a Line Break?

Tags: linux, bash, terraform, devops, terraform0.12+

In standard shell, you can include a line break as so:

```
  $a="line1\nline2"
```

But in this command:

```
resource "null_resource" "crypt_folio" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "echo 'line1\nline2' > filo.txt"
    }
}
```

It will fail.

How to properly escape a line break? I tried a second backslash, and this similarly failed.

Comment: If what you really need is to provide content for a local file like what you are attempting above, then you can solve your problem with https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file.

Comment: Update, double escaping it using a triple backslash: \\\n also fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the -e flag on may do the trick:
**echo **-e** 'line1\nline2' > filo.txt**

Comment: Just to be clear having the single quotes inside the double quotes was also needed. But yes, the secret sauce is "echo -e". Brilliant answer. ```resource "null_resource" "crypt_folio" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "echo -e 'line1\nline2' > filo.txt"
    }
}```